# Excel VBA refedit Issues

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm hoping this is an easy one for someone...

I have a userform that allows users to select cells from rows they would like to delete. There is no problem with any of the code. Everything works as expected with a single exception. When selecting cells using the refedit tool there is no outline around the cells I'm selecting like you would expect to see.

I have searched up and down the internet and I cannot find a single mention of anyone having this same issue much less a fix for it. I also took note of the default properties and then started playing around with those. Still no outline. All videos I have found so far show the cells being outlined as the user drags their cursor over them seemingly without changing any properties. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Application.ScreenUpdating set to False before the refedit ?

Comment: That seems to have been the case. Is that the default behavior when a userform initializes without an initialization routine? There isn't anything I can think of that sets it to false within my code. But when I added an initialization routine setting to true the problem was fixed. Either way, thank you! I was going crazy trying to fix that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's the simplest things that get you... Thank you @Matr1x

"Do you have Application.ScreenUpdating set to False before the refedit ?" –
Matr1x